# Finding the previous month

Tags: python

I've seen some methods using `dateutil` module to do this, but is there a way to do this without just using the built in libs?

For example, the current month right now is July. I can do this using the `datetime.now()` function.

What would be the easiest way for python to return the previous month?

Comment: Why the restriction on using libraries, and why is the `datetime` module exempt from it?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist it's not uncommon to make an exception for libraries that are included with the language, i.e. don't need to be installed.

Comment: @MarkRansom That's a great guess. I would like for the OP to update their question with _their_ reason.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's very easy:

```
>>> previous_month = datetime.now().month - 1
>>> if previous_month == 0:
...     previous_month = 12
```

Comment: You can one-line it with `previous_month = datetime.now().month - 1 or 12`.

Comment: I think using `(datetime.now().month - 1) % 12` is possibly a bit neater as it works if you subtract (or add) different numbers instead of 1. It also expresses the intent more clearly as years cycling is a textbook case of modular arithmetic. This is all pretty subjective though....

Comment: One-lining is code golf. Code golf is unpythonic. Code should have a clear and easily understandable intent, especially when written for newbies. ;-)

Comment: Its ok, I understood both answers pretty well. :)

Comment: I figured out solution without condition. `previous_month = (datetime.now().month - 2) % 12 + 1`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`calendar`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html) module

```
>>> from calendar import  month_name, month_abbr
>>> d = datetime.now()
>>> month_name[d.month - 1] or month_name[-1]
'June'
>>> month_abbr[d.month - 1] or month_abbr[-1]
'Jun'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking about the shortest solution and I figured out it without using condition.

```
current_month = datetime.now().month
previous_month = (current_month - 2) % 12 + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want it as a string then do below process.

```
import datetime
months =(" Blank", "December", "January", "February", "March", "April", 
 "May","June", "July","August","September","October","November")
d = datetime.date.today()
print(months[d.month])
```

Answer (score 0):

Generalized function finding the year and month, based on a month delta:

```py
# %% function
def get_year_month(ref_date, month_delta):
    year_delta, month_index = divmod(ref_date.month - 1 + month_delta, 12)
    year = ref_date.year + year_delta
    month = month_index + 1
    return year, month

# %% test
some_date = date(2022, 5, 31)
for delta in range(-12, 12):
    year, month = get_year_month(some_date, delta)
    print(f"{delta=}, {year=}, {month=}")
```

```sh
delta=-12, year=2021, month=5
delta=-11, year=2021, month=6
delta=-10, year=2021, month=7
delta=-9, year=2021, month=8
delta=-8, year=2021, month=9
delta=-7, year=2021, month=10
delta=-6, year=2021, month=11
delta=-5, year=2021, month=12
delta=-4, year=2022, month=1
delta=-3, year=2022, month=2
delta=-2, year=2022, month=3
delta=-1, year=2022, month=4
delta=0, year=2022, month=5
delta=1, year=2022, month=6
delta=2, year=2022, month=7
delta=3, year=2022, month=8
delta=4, year=2022, month=9
delta=5, year=2022, month=10
delta=6, year=2022, month=11
delta=7, year=2022, month=12
delta=8, year=2023, month=1
delta=9, year=2023, month=2
delta=10, year=2023, month=3
delta=11, year=2023, month=4
```

Answer (score -4):

If you want a date object:

```
import datetime
d = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)
>>> datetime.date(2015, 6, 29)
```

Comment: @MarkRansom  You're right, it needs some adaptation. By the way, the duration _month_ can have different meanings ;-)

Comment: The question asks for the previous month, though, rather than for the date a month ago.

Comment: It doesn't need adaptation, it's fundamentally wrong. Welcome to the world of calendaring, where nothing is as easy as you think. ;-) And that's even before we get to time zones.